# Display properties name for custom properties in Swagger

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a property named UserLanguage whose type is Language ( a record that I created ) which has three properties Name,Alpha2Code and Alpha3Code.

So in my request models, I give property as Language but on swagger, it only appears like this

```
{
  "name" : "",
  "userlanguage" : {}
}
```

I want to appear like this :

```
 {
      "name" : "",
      "userLanguage" : {
          "name" : "",
          "alpha2Code" : "",
          "alpha3Code" : ""
       }
 }
```

This is the language record:

```
public record Language
{
    public static readonly Language None = new(string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty);
    
    private Language(
        string alpha2Code, 
        string alpha3Code,
        string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Alpha2Code = alpha2Code;
        Alpha3Code = alpha3Code;
    }
    public string Alpha2Code { get; private set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Alpha3Code { get; private set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? Name { get; private set; }
}
```

This is the request:

```
public sealed record UserDetailsRequest(
    string Name,
    Language UserLanguage
);
```

How can I achieve it in .NET 6 Web API?

Comment: Could you show the attributes on the properties of the model?

Comment: That is just a immutable record with properties name and types. No attributes.

Comment: dose your property has a setter? could you share the model?

Comment: @RuikaiFeng check the question now

Comment: You need a filter for the properties have a private setter,also ,you'd better modify the constructor to public

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the properties with a private setter,you would need a filter:

```
 public class AddPrivateSetPropertyFilter : ISchemaFilter
 {
     public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
     {
         if (schema?.Properties?.Count > 0)
             schema.Properties.Values.SingleOrDefault(v => v.ReadOnly = false);
     }
 }
```

Apply it in program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c=> c.SchemaFilter<AddPrivateSetPropertyFilter>());
```

It's ok onmyside:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
public class UserLanguage
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Alpha2Code { get; set; }
    public string Alpha3Code { get; set; }
}

public class YourRequestModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public UserLanguage UserLanguage { get; set; }
}

// In your Controller
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class YourController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("yourEndpoint")]
    public IActionResult YourEndpoint([FromBody] YourRequestModel model)
    {
        // Your endpoint logic here
        return Ok();
    }
}
```